# CarPlay parking app crashed when launching from Xcode 12.5.1 CarPlay simulator

Tags: swift, carplay

I'm new in iOS development. Got task on job to extend our iOS app with CarPlay. I created class 'CarPlaySceneDelegate' as entry point for Car Play. Code is below:

```
class CarPlaySceneDelegate: UIResponder, CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate {
    var interfaceController: CPInterfaceController?
    
    func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
                                  didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
        self.interfaceController = interfaceController
        ...
        interfaceController.setRootTemplate(tabBarTemplate, animated: true)
        
  }        

    private func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene,
          didDisconnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
          self.interfaceController = nil
    }
}
```

To Info.plist I added this configuration:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Configuration Name</key>
                    <string>Default configuration</string>
                    <key>Delegate Class Name</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>Storyboard Name</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>BlueGate-Car</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarPlaySceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

On launching on simulator CarPlay launches good according to CarPlaySceneDelegate class. But on iPhone Simulator it's not launched at all. App loads and screen become black.

In console:

```
2021-11-03 12:45:11.228204+0200 BlueGate[5806:119147]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
2021-11-03 10:45:11 +0000 [AppDelegate.swift]:[application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)][103:19] start function
2021-11-03 12:45:11.714422+0200 BlueGate[5806:118883] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 8.7.0
2021-11-03 12:45:12.108628+0200 BlueGate[5806:119153] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.8.7.0 started
2021-11-03 12:45:12.119347+0200 BlueGate[5806:119153] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://<someLink>)
2021-11-03 12:45:12.140585+0200 BlueGate[5806:119154] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025036] App Delegate Proxy is disabled
2021-11-03 10:45:12 +0000 [AppDelegate.swift]:[configureNetworkMonitoring()][89:35] Network is ON
2021-11-03 12:45:12.316632+0200 BlueGate[5806:119154] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '188981723956'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
2021-11-03 12:45:17.626397+0200 BlueGate[5806:119147] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2021-11-03 12:45:17.735262+0200 BlueGate[5806:119147] 8.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
```

My environment Xcode 12.5.1

Did I do anything wrong or Is there any other way I can implement the CarPlay part feature by Xcode/swift while keeping the mobile app on iOS?

Appreciate any comments or help.

Comment: If I remove UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication from Info.plist nothing changes

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is. "On launching on simulator CarPlay launches good" / "on iPhone Simulator it's not launched": Do you mean your CarPlay app launches when starting the CarPlay simulator via I/O-External Displays-CarPlay... but your iOS app is NOT launching anymore since your changes?

Answer (score 0):

The keys of your application scene in the plist seem to be wrong. Try using `UISceneConfigurationName` instead of `Configuration Name`, `UISceneDelegateClassName` instead of `Delegate Class Name` and `UILaunchStoryboardName` instead of `Storyboard Name`.